# How to remove (pop) a view from OTHER view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have 2 views. One is the 'viewheader' and the other is the 'viewContent' (added as subview).

'viewContent' contains a TableView (based on UINavigationController) and the TableView can drill down to a DetailView (UIViewController). (see Image below)

**My Question is:** How can I remove (pop) the DetailView, with a UIButton **FROM** the 'headerView'.

The goal is to create a fixed Navigation, and only change (animate) the lower Content.

**Thanks**

```
// add "fixed" Header
- (void)loadView {
    viewHeader = [[HeaderViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HeaderViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.view = viewHeader.view;
}

// add content view
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    viewContent = [[MainContentViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainContentViewController" bundle:nil];

    CGRect viewFrame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 164.0f, 320, 316);
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewContent];
    [navController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    [navController.view setFrame:viewFrame];
    viewHeader.contentNavView = navController; // <<<< CAN'T POP THE VIEW by passing UINavigationController to "header view"
    [self.view addSubview:navController.view];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found my mistake. The definition of 'contentNavView' inside 'viewheader' was wrong

Changed it from UIViewController to UINavigationController.

```
@interface HeaderViewController : UIViewController {
    UINavigationController *contentNavView;
}
...
```

Calling

```
[contentNavView pushViewController:aViewController animated:NO];
```

works.

Answer (score 0):

You must somehow send a `removeFromSuperview` message to the detail view when the button on the header view is tapped (i.e. an `IBAction` is triggered). You can achieve this by either making the detail view a property of the header view controller to be able to call the `removeFromSuperview` of the detail view in your header view's `IBAction`.
Or if you prefer loose coupling (which you should), post a notification from the `IBAction`in the header view and register for that notification in the detail view with a method that removes the detail view from the header view.